# MySql using DATEDIFF inside IF clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement, datediff

I'm trying to use DATEDIFF function inside an IF clause as the following:

```
select if('2006-04-01',DATEDIFF('2006-04-01','2007-04-01'),'y');
```

But the result I get is `BLOB`!!

How Can I use `DATEDIFF` within an `IF` statement and get a meaningful result.

Thank you all

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may misunderstood the if function

```
select if( datediff('2006-04-01','2012-01-01') > 0, 1, 0 );
```

works very well

The result of datediff in my case mysql 5.5.24 is an integer.

Comment: can we check one more condition in the same if statement with && condition

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the `if` statement works as follows:

```
select if(expr, true, false)
```

Also, `DATEDIFF` returns an int not a date, so you would want to take the return value of `DATADIFF` and compare it against a known number of days or 0 perhaps, or the return of another `DATEDIFF` operation.

```
select if(datediff(date1, date2) >= 20, 'true statement', 'false statement')
```